# How do I fix "`as_number' is not a Pari function name" in Math::Pari called by Math::BigInt?

Tags: perl, cpan

On Perl 5.8.5 I am seeing the error listed in the question.

I am running these version modules:

- Math::BigInt: 1.89
- Math::BigInt::FastCalc: 0.19
- Math::BigInt::GMP: 1.24
- Math::BigInt::Pari: 1.13
- Math::BigRat: 0.22
- bignum: 0.22

The module producing the error is Math::Pari.  This is all in an attempt to get Net::SFTP working to put a file on a remote host.

Thanks for any insight, oh CPAN gurus.  :)

---

Thanks, nothingmuch, I tried those things but when I remove Math::Pari, Net::SSH::Perl::Util::SSH2MP complains because it is using it as such:

```
use Math::Pari qw( PARI floor pari2num Mod lift );
```

The Math::Pari version is 2.010800

I wish I understood the CPAN build process better so I could know if this was worth reporting to the maintainer of Net::SFTP.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would probably just to remove Math::BigInt::Pari. GMP should be able to do everything you need.

You can also prepend your script with

```
use Math::BigInt only => "GMP";
```

or something like that (see the Math::BigInt docs) to ensure that calc module is used instead of Math::Pari.

Make sure that this use line appears before anything else that may load Math::BigInt differently.

Comment: Not sure if the issue might be that Math::Pari is the module coughing the error, not Math::BigInt::Pari.

Comment: This solution didn't help for me, and I'm having the same warning when using Net::FTP.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever it is worth: For me the problem was related to the SSH protocol used on the target host. It was set to SSH version 2. I temporarily removed it and Net:SSH now works for me. Not a solution, but at least a workaround.