# How do I fix "as_number is not a Pari function name" when using Perl Net::SSH::Perl module

Tags: perl

I ran into this problem when trying to run a command via Net::SSH:Perl on another Linux host. Here is the exact error:

```
`as_number' is not a Pari function name  Line 1148.
 5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Math/Pari.pm
```

I found only one relevant posting and it indicates that it could be some sort of version mismatch between some of the Perl libraries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix "`as_number' is not a Pari function name" in Math::Pari called by Math::BigInt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418347/how-do-i-fix-as-number-is-not-a-pari-function-name-in-mathpari-called-by-ma)

Answer (score 2):

See this question: [How do I fix “`as_number’ is not a Pari function name” in Math::Pari called by Math::BigInt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418347).